# sharepoint user profie picture

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, sharepoint-addin, jquery, rest

I have created an app part that collects the current user profile picture

```
 function GetCurrentUser() {
            $.ajax({
                url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties?$select=PictureUrl",
                type: "GET",
                headers: {
                    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    var picUrl = data.d.PictureUrl;
                    $('#bild').attr('src', picUrl);

                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(error));
                }
            });
        }
```

I get an error message "_spPageContextInfo is not defined"

and when I put this line of code `<SharePoint:SharePointForm runat="server" ></SharePoint:SharePointForm>`

I get the error message [image]

will be grateful if you could help me to solve it

Comment: ?? Are you trying to run Client-Side code Server-Side? _spPageContextInfo exists in the Browser

Comment: im running Client-Side Code

Comment: When removing "_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl " from my code, I get the error message " readystate 4 responsetext status 404 statustext not found"

Comment: Where is "GetCurrentUser" executing on the page? If you view source for the page, you should see where "_spPageContextInfo" is defined. If it is defined after your script executes , that would explain the error. Make sure "GetCurrentUser" is executed after the dom is ready. jQuery(function(){ GetCurrentUser(); });

Comment: here is the whole kode  window._spPageContextInfo{crossDomainContextPhotosEnabled: true }; jQuery(document).ready(function () {GetCurrentUser();function GetCurrentUser() {$.ajax({url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl+"/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties?$select=PictureURL",type: "GET",headers: {"accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",},success: function (data) {var userName = data.d.DisplayName;var picUrl = data.d.PictureUrl;$('#bild').attr('src', picUrl);}, error: function (error) {
alert(JSON.stringify(error));
}
});
  }
        });`